# Where is AutowirePartialView Bindable Property gone?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Before upgrading to Prism 8 I was using the bindable property `ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView` to set the binding context of ContentViews.

This property is now gone and I can't find any documentation about how to replace it.

Do I have to stick with Prism 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView` was removed in [Prism 8.0.0.1909](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v8.0.0.1909). Although it is not mentioned in the release notes, you can refer to [this pull request](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/commit/b70f870755d7e55c85a9aaa83a46989b3b86241c#diff-fc204228dc3c64cd2f328b07c2b0d1d83d3a0af2c83df97abb3edba0f396e8a1).

In [Prism 8.1 questions](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/discussions/2548), you get an official answer, which is to use regions instead.

> > Because `AutowirePartialView` is no longer available in Prism 8.1 do we need to use regions now? Are regions compatible with third party TabView control?
>
> The short answer here is that yes you do need to use Regions. Regions are compatible with 3rd party controls, however you will need to create and register the Adapters for the 3rd party controls yourself.